# methoderror: no method matching isless(::Float64, ::Array{Float64, 2})

Tags: arrays, julia

for `if abs(J .- J2) <= epsilon`, how do I compare the difference of each row in the `abs(J .- J2)` array of floats to the epsilon float?

Comment: what are the shapes of J and J2? can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you need but if you want to check if all entries in a row meet the predicate (separately for every row) you can use `mapslices(any, abs.(J .- J2) .<= epsilon, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you're trying to solve, there's already an inbuilt function [isapprox](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/math/#Base.isapprox) that compared values for a given  tolerance (`epsilon` in the question).

`if isapprox(J, J2; atol=epsilon, rtol=0)` will compare the elements in J against those in J2, and return true if the absolute difference between each pair of elements is less than the given `atol` value.